# Istio route rules

Tags: rest, http, routes, istio, envoyproxy

I'm trying to set some route rules and I have a problem in the following case. If I send a HTTP request to the port, let's say, 5000 of the service "service-a" I want my route rule to forward the request to the port 5001 of the service "service-b". Is it possible?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-route
spec:
  hosts:
  - service-a:5000
  - service-a
  - service-a.service:5000
  - service-a.service
  - service-a.service.consul:5000
  - service-a.service.consul
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/v1/service-a"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/v1/ser-a"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 5001
        name: service-b
```

The gateway was defined as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-gatweway-controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 5000
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - localhost
  - port:
      number: 5001
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - localhost
```

The result is an internal error 500 and the request lands on port 5000 instead on 5001. Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Best regards

Martin

Answer (score 0):

The port rewriting was fixed three days ago by this PR - https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/5543, it should appear in the next release of Istio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vadim!

Comment: Hello Vadim, is there already a release date for the new release published? I have not found anything online. Best regards

Comment: I do not know when is Istio 0.8 release date, sorry.